# File attachments in Blocks?

Tags: drupal, file-upload, drupal-6

Whats the best way to have file attachments in blocks like you can with nodes? Is this possible with an existing module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your attachments are CCK File fields, you can use [CCK Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/cck_blocks) module for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best course of action, is to create a block and then create a view of the node with a block display. With a bit of work you could automate the process, and don't publish the node if you prefer it not being viewable.

You could create a base view in the views UI and export it, the only thing you would need to configure is the node id.

That is one way of doing this, that doesn't require too much work, and utilize a lot of modules you probably already have enabled for the site.

Answer (score 1):

Use views, create a block display and set it to display file attachments for the specific node type. Set the argument to node ID by providing a default argument and telling to fetch the node ID from the URL.

Bam!